# Возможна ли корректная работа команды make в Windows при наличии "./" в Makefile?

Tags: gradle, powershell, makefile

Работаю на Windows. Терминал - PowerShell. Столкнулся, думаю, с понятной проблемой наличия разных слешей в путях Windows и Linux. Содержимое Makefile:

```
install:
    ./gradlew clean install
```

Команда `./gradlew clean install` в терминале срабатывает, но `make install`  - нет, и терминал выдаёт понятную ошибку:

> "." не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
> программой или пакетным файлом.

Если в Makefile поменять слеш на обратный, то команда `make install` начнёт работать. Содержимое Makefile будет следующим:

```
install:
    .\gradlew clean install
```

Основной вопрос: есть ли какой-то способ заставить команду `make` работать с первоначальным содержимым? Так как иначе Makefile выходит бесполезным для пользователя Windows. Его нужно будет переделывать под себя. Хочется найти способ сокращения временных затрат, чтобы файл подходил для работы и на Unix-системах, и на Windows. Многочасовое гугление и использование git bash вместо PowerShell эффекта не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо того, что бы каждый раз писать

```
./gradlew
```

надо сделать так

```
GRADLEW=./gradlew
```

и теперь команды будут такие

```
install:
    $(GRADLEW) clean install
```

теперь у Вас будет только одно место, где находится полное имя команды.

Теперь вторая половина квеста. Смотрите в [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile) и пишите где то такое

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  GRADLEW=.\gradlew
else
  GRADLEW=./gradlew
endif
```

если что, дописываете правильные условия под Ваши потребности. И готово.

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема cmd, связанная с обратной совместимостью с MS-DOS, в которой пользователям разрешалось пропускать пробел между исполнимым файлом и первым аргументом если тот начинается со знака `/`.

И обход этой проблемы также известен, попробуйте вот так:

```
install:
    "./gradlew" clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

Такие проблемы возникают, если Make использует `cmd` в качестве шелла, вместо `sh`, который используется на линуксе. Видимо разные версии Make по-разному выбирают себе шелл.

Если поставить `make` или `mingw32-make` из [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), то в их версии всегда используется `sh`, и линуксовые мейкфайлы должны работать из коробки.

Их `make` - точная имитация того, что на линуксе. В их `mingw32-make` функции работы с путями оперируют виндовыми путями, а не линуксовыми, поэтому какие-то сложные мейкфайлы могут не работать. Зато он тормозит меньше.